# Why do most journals use separate manuscript submission systems?

Tags: journals, paper-submission, software, workflow

As you all are familiar, most journals use manuscripts submission systems hosted on some separate domain. Why is that so, are there some other benefits except separation of the presentation layer and the editorial layer?

Open source solutions such as OJS (Open Journal System) provide both of these functionalities on a single domain.

Is this the case only because different parties provide software for these functionalities or there is some other reason to do so?

Comment: Because there is $ to be made.

Comment: In any case a provider would earn $. I don't think that a provider would need to give or sell their manuscript submission system. They could still be in a SaS arrangement with the journal owners but just use single domain or journal domain and subdomain.

Comment: One possibility is that they are in a SaS (software as service) agreement with some provider that doesn't offer the option to customize the domain, or charges extra for it.

Answer (score 16):

Most well known journals started online submissions before there were open source solutions available (I make no value judgement on how good the open source systems are). Now, they have decades of experience with (and data in) their own system. If it works, don't break it.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to Jon Custer's answer, let me also point out that it is good practice to host data that is sensitive on separate systems. The editorial systems hold reviews, reviewer identities, editor comments, and other data that should really not become public. It needs to be guarded more cautiously than the data that sits on a public-facing web server like those used to provide access to papers. Hacking one should not give an attacker access to the other.

Comment: Yes I understand your point, I think that is the main reason for separation. But also, some journals like a PeerJ, Frontiers, go with one domain, Hindawi and MDPI use subdomains. An subdomain should provide the same lavel of saparation (Protection) as separate domain as I see it, but most journals still go with domains of their editorial workflow providers. It seem to me that that is so also due to protection of editorial platform source code.

Comment: Yes, BUT whether this is on the same frontend domain/directory or not is pretty much irrelevant. - That is an infrastructure question that does not have any bearing on what the user sees on the frontend. - I.e. I can have a subdirectory on a website hosted on another server or a subdomain, etc. The user does not need to see this. - Incidentally, just seperating something into a second domain doesn't do anything for security on its own. - And if you can log into a system (to submit, review for example) it is just as public facing as the main site providing published papers.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the existing answers: some journals (e.g. some of those those known as 'society journals', because they are connected to [learned societies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learned_society)) are editorially independent, but contract with some external publishing company who provides the infrastructure of manuscript handling, copy-editing and dissemination. In such circumstances the journal domain may be that of the society, whereas the submission domain belongs to whoever currently holds the publishing contract.

Comment: Yes, it is not rare to have such connections but I don't see a reason why a journal domain could not be used by some external provider also. Afterall, journal website is also provided by some other provider?